# Zipkin : zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter flush Dropped 1 spans due to SocketTimeoutException(connect timed out)

Tags: java, zipkin, brave

Small Zipkin question, how to set the time out please?

I am writing a very simple piece of code, where I am the **client**, and sending requests to a server.

```
import brave.Span;
import brave.Tracing;
import zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter;
import zipkin2.reporter.okhttp3.OkHttpSender;

public class QuestionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        var sender = OkHttpSender.newBuilder().endpoint("http://zipkin-server:9411/api/v2/spans").build();
        var reporter = AsyncReporter.builder(sender).build();
        
        var tracing = Tracing.newBuilder().localServiceName("component-test").spanReporter(reporter).build();
        
        // Create parent span and his child --------------------
        
        // Parent
        tracing.tracer().startScopedSpan("parentSpan");
        Span span =  tracing.tracer().currentSpan();
        span.tag("key", "firstBiz");
        
        // Child
        tracing.tracer().startScopedSpanWithParent("childSpan", tracing.tracer().currentSpan().context());
        Span childSpan =  tracing.tracer().currentSpan();
        childSpan.tag("key", "secondBiz");
        childSpan.finish();
        System.out.println("id:" + childSpan.context().traceIdString());
      final var response      = webClient.post().uri("http://the-server.com/api/route").header("X-B3-TraceId", childSpan.context().traceIdString()).body(BodyInserters.fromValue(jsonPayload)).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
        System.out.println(response);
        
        // Finish span
        span.finish();
        
       
    }

}
```

Reproducible 100%, I am always getting this error:

```
zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter flush
WARNING: Spans were dropped due to exceptions. All subsequent errors will be logged at FINE level.
zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter flush
WARNING: Dropped 1 spans due to SocketTimeoutException(connect timed out)
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
    at zipkin2.reporter.okhttp3.HttpCall.execute(HttpCall.java:34)
    at zipkin2.reporter.okhttp3.HttpCall.execute(HttpCall.java:25)
    at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter.flush(AsyncReporter.java:299)
    at zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$Flusher.run(AsyncReporter.java:378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

zipkin2.reporter.AsyncReporter$BoundedAsyncReporter close
WARNING: Timed out waiting for in-flight spans to send
```

I tried looking at the internal API for a method to set the time out, but no luck.

May I ask what is the proper way to set the time out please?

Thank you